# Is `nginx -s` the same as `service nginx`?

Tags: linux, nginx

I noticed that many of the commands like `nginx -s reload` and `nginx -s stop` seem to be (almost?) the same as `service nginx reload` and `service nginx stop`.

Are those "prefixes" actually interchangable? Does one of them somehow invoke the other?

Comment: What system and version are you running?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Ubuntu Server 18.04 and Nginx 1.14.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are running Ubuntu 18.04 (i.e. a recent Linux distribution), I might suggest a third *“alias”* command: `systemctl reload nginx` and `/etc/init.d/nginx reload`.

The whole story is this: every server/application has its own way to start, stop, reload, etc. This might be as simple as calling `nginx` or complicated as setting several environment variables and calling `java <a_lot_of_options> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start` for Tomcat.

In order to provide a uniform and automatic way to start applications, distributions provide init scripts (or similar), which on a new Ubuntu come in three variants:

1. The modern **systemd**: `systemctl <verb> nginx`,
2. The legacy (for Ubuntu) **upstart**: `service nginx <verb>`,
3. The oldest **SysV init**: `/etc/init.d/nginx <verb>`.

On Ubuntu **systemd** is the actual one running, while the other ones call **systemd**. The configuration (`/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service` file) for nginx contains:

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;' -s reload
ExecStop=-/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid
```

So:

- `systemctl reload nginx` calls `nginx -s reload`, but with the additional option `-g 'daemon on; master_process on;'`, which overrides these two configuration options,
- `systemctl stop nginx` uses a helper program `start-stop-daemon` to supervise **nginx** shutdown. This program will send a `SIGQUIT` signal to nginx, which is the same as `nginx -s quit`, wait 5 seconds and if nginx is still running announce failure.

In general it is better to use the `systemctl <verb> <service>` commands instead of starting applications by themselves.

**Edit**: Actually **systemd** does much more than executing the command: it connects its input/output to **systemd-journald**, it limits the resources at its disposal ([cgroups](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroups.7.html)) and the visibility of other parts of the system ([namespaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html)), it configures the process [capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) and probably something more.